# Templates cannot convert from 'const _Ty' to 'T'

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm writing a simple code to get the min and max value from a vector by using algorithm min and max 
respectively. 
But I'm getting 2 erros: 'return': cannot convert from 'const _Ty' to 'T'

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
T minValue(std::vector<T> v) {
    return min(v.begin(),v.end());
}

template<typename T>
T maxValue(std::vector<T> v) {
    return max(v.begin(),v.end());
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,15,3,4,5,0 };
    std::cout << "The min value is: " << minValue(v) << "\n";
    std::cout << "The max value is: " << maxValue(v) << "\n";
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: [`min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)/[`max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) don't have overloads operating on ranges. You want `min_element`/`max_element`.

Answer (score 1):

Use *min_element and *max_element instead of min and max respectively.

```
template<typename T>
T minValue(std::vector<T> v) {
    return *min_element(v.begin(),v.end());
}

template<typename T>
T maxValue(std::vector<T> v) {
    return *max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
}
```